How to avoid circular relations in postgres using cycle detection
I'm trying to use CYCLE detection in PostgreSQL to avoid circular nesting of groups but cannot figure it out.
I have the following PostgreSQL 16 table:
CREATE TABLE groups (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  name text NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO groups (name)
VALUES
  ('group1'),
  ('group2'),
  ('group3'),
  ('group4');

SELECT * FROM groups;

Output:



id
name




1
group1


2
group2


3
group3


4
group4



And the following junction table:
CREATE TABLE related_groups_self (
  parent_id integer REFERENCES groups (id), 
  child_id integer REFERENCES groups (id),
  PRIMARY KEY (parent_id, child_id)
);

INSERT INTO related_groups_self (parent_id, child_id) 
VALUES
    (1, 2),
    (2, 3),
    (3, 4);

SELECT * FROM related_groups_self

Output:



parent_id
child_id




1
2


2
3


3
4



If my app user was to attempt to add group 4 as the parent of group 1; (4, 1), how can I detect this using CYCLE detection?
I want to avoid inserting the tuple until after the check has verified as safe from circular nesting, so the incorrect entry won't exist in the junction table already.
I'm no DBA, and I've been banging my head against this issue using multiple different methods from various blog posts on the subject with very little success. Here's the latest effort, although obviously not working:
WITH RECURSIVE tree AS (
    SELECT child_id, 1 AS level
    FROM related_groups_self rgs
    WHERE rgs.parent_id = 1
  UNION
    SELECT rgs.child_id, tree.level + 1
    FROM tree
    JOIN related_groups_self as rgs ON(tree.child_id = rgs.parent_id)
) CYCLE child_id SET is_cycle USING cycle_path
SELECT * FROM tree;

Any help would be appreciated

Have you read this: https://blog.mergify.com/cycle-detection-in-postgresql/ ?

Yeh, I have. I didn't want to use triggers though. We've avoided them in our code base up until now as they can be hard to debug. We're about to handover to devs that are even less experienced with DBs than ourselves, so we still want to avoid them if possible.

If you want to prevent cycles you don't have to use the CYCLE keyword, since you don't have cycle to begin with.
Instead if you want to add the connection A->B you must ensure that no path from B->A exists.
To do this you can start with a select giving you all paths:
with recursive tree(parent) as (
    select r.parent_id, r.child_id, 0 level
    from related_groups_self as r
  UNION ALL
    select r.parent_id, r.child_id, t.level + 1 level
    from related_groups_self as r, tree t
    where r.parent_id = t.child_id
  
)
select * from tree

Now limit it to those connecting the end points of the potential new connection:

with recursive tree(parent) as (
    select r.parent_id, r.child_id, 0 level
    from related_groups_self as r
    where r.parent_id = 1 -- new child id
  UNION ALL
    select r.parent_id, r.child_id, t.level + 1 level
    from related_groups_self as r, tree t
    where r.parent_id = t.child_id
  
)
select * from tree
where child_id = 4 -- new parent id

Note that we can limit the parent_id on the inside of the recursive select, because the path has to start there. But we have to limit the child_id on the outside because intermediate steps might go through other child_id values.
We can further tune this by limiting the result to 1 row or by using an exists construct. What exactly to use depends on where you want to use this:
with recursive tree(parent) as (
    select r.parent_id, r.child_id, 0 level
    from related_groups_self as r
    where r.parent_id = 1 -- new child id
  UNION ALL
    select r.parent_id, r.child_id, t.level + 1 level
    from related_groups_self as r, tree t
    where r.parent_id = t.child_id
  
)
select * from tree
where child_id = 4 -- new parent id
limit 1

DB Fiddle
When applying this test you must ensure that no inserts or updates happen between your check and the insert, which probably means a table lock.
Alternatively you could allow cycles to exist for a short time and run checks on a regular basis, possibly after every table update in order to eliminate them.

Came back here because I was having issues with integrating the previously accepted answer into my app. I'm using TypeScript with a Kysely postgres adapter and the return value of cycle_err:  {(1),(2),(3),(4)} would only ever show as undefined for some reason. Not sure why. Your example worked straight out of the box when porting it over to TypeScript. Thank you

I think it's still worth checking for a loop in the query itself. As a result of competitive access or for some other reason, cycles may created and then the request will end with  error by running out of allocated memory or the allowed number of recursions.

Check cycle before insertion.
See example
WITH RECURSIVE tree AS (
          -- 1 - new child
    SELECT 1 child_id, 1 AS level
  UNION
    SELECT rgs.child_id, tree.level + 1
    FROM tree
    JOIN related_groups_self as rgs ON(tree.child_id = rgs.parent_id)
) CYCLE child_id SET is_cycle USING cycle_path
                                           -- 4 - new parent
SELECT  (select cycle_path FROM tree where child_id=4) cycle_err;

Result is



cycle_err




{(1),(2),(3),(4)}



If result is null - insertion do not create cycle.



cycle_err




null



demo

Thank you so much, this works perfectly. You've just saved me from a sleepless night :-)
